# How to correctly show the closing } on rules?

Tags: sass

I've been playing with **SCSS** to try and clean up a new stylesheet I'm working on. I love it so far! Simple, yet powerful. One issue I'm finding though, is the closing `}` brackets. For example, I'm compiling it with:

```
 sass --watch ./main.scss:../main.css
```

...and with the following SCSS:

```
#moreFilterOptionsBtn {
  text-align: center;font-size: 1.6em;

  a {
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
  }

}
```

You get:

```
#moreFilterOptionsBtn {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6em; }
  #moreFilterOptionsBtn a {
    background: none;
    padding: 0; }
```

How can I get it to format it better? ie

```
#moreFilterOptionsBtn {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6em; 
}
  #moreFilterOptionsBtn a {
    background: none;
    padding: 0; 
  }
```

i.e putting the closing } on a new line, instead of squished up on the end of the rule? For me, this is *much* more readble!

Thanks

Comment: Why does the formatting matter?  No one will be editing the compiled CSS and dev tools will handle it correctly.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - so you are telling me you don't "read" the outputted CSS file, to check for syntax? Thats what I'm doing, and thats why I need it to be formatted better. I actually found the solution anyway - using `--style expanded` (see answer below). I will eventually be minifying these CSS files anyway, but for the dev time I need to be able to check them

Comment: Nope, never looked at it, never heard of anyone checking it.  SASS is very reliable.  If you wrote a rule that isn't what you thought, you'll discover it in dev tools.  Glad you found an answer. :)

Comment: Its still quite new to me. I'm sure I will learn to trust it in the future - but for now I like to see what its outputting, so I can be sure its doing what I think it is hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical! I just found out about the **--style** value in CLI:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style

Just add `--style expanded` to the end, and it will format correctly:

```
 sass --watch ./main.scss:../main.css --style expanded
```